# Using WebClient DownloadString, how can I get a JSON API Result in plaintext?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to make the text plaintext rather than JSON formatting. How can I accomplish this? I've searched around but I haven't been able to come across a quick and easy solution that works. Having tried for a long time, I apologise in advance if this seems like a ridiculous question.

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
}
        
string pubIp = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://vpnapi.io/api/?key=APIKEY");

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text =  "IP Address: " + pubIp + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

It currently appears as this (but line by line):

```
{
    "ip": "1.1.1.1.1.1",
    "security": {
        "vpn": false,
        "proxy": false,
        "tor": false,
        "relay": false
    },
    "location": {
        "city": "Location",
        "region": "Location",
        "country": "Location",
        "continent": "Location",
        "region_code": "Location",
        "country_code": "Location",
        "continent_code": "Location",
        "latitude": "-00.0000",
        "longitude": "000.0000",
        "time_zone": "Location",
        "locale_code": "en",
        "metro_code": "",
        "is_in_european_union": false
    },
    "network": {
        "network": "1.111.1.1/11",
        "autonomous_system_number": "111111",
        "autonomous_system_organization": "ISP"
    }
}
```

I would like it to appear like this:

```
ip: 1.1.1.1.1.1 
security vpn: 
false proxy: 
false tor: 
false relay: false

location: city: 
Location region: 
Location country: 
Location continent: 
Location region_code: 
Location country_code: 
Location continent_code: 
Location latitude: -00.0000 
longitude: 000.0000 time_zone: 
Location locale_code: 
metro_code: 
is_in_european_union": false

network network: 1.111.1.1/11 
autonomous_system_number: 111111 
autonomous_system_organization: ISP
```

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you want with `DownloadString` as it does not perform any transformations. It is possible that your restrictions are not as strict as specified in the post and you are interested in something quite different what is written in the question currently. Consider to [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Deserialize your JSON to a model, then override `ToString()` of the, e.g., Root class. Return whatever you see fit in the override.